# MongoDB: creating collection with multiple components

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[image]

I'm working with node and mongo 5. I want to create a new collection made out of 2 components out of a preexisting collection. The first component has 'PENALTIES' not equal 0. I can get this component with

```
 {"PENALTIES": {$ne: "$0.00"}}
```

Next I want to get the component with Penalties 0, Interest not equal 0 . I can get this with:

```
{$and:[{"PENALTIES": {$eq: "$0.00"}}, {"INTEREST": {$ne: "$0.00"}}]}
```

Is there a way to assemble these into a collection with component 1 followed by component 2?

(Sample record below)

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6386d07324da3f53abd52449"
    },
    "RowId": 0,
    "ParcelUse": "2",
    "UseDefinition": "",  
    "AMOUNT": "$0.00",
    "CERT NO  ": "",
    "FEES": "$0.00",
    "INTEREST": "$0.00",
    "INTEREST DATE": "",
    "INTERESTPERCENT": "",
    "PAY": "",
    "PENALTIES": "$0.00",
    "TAX YEAR": "",
    "TOTAL DUE": "$0.00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$unionWith` to chain up the results from 2 criteria and `$merge` to a new collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "PENALTIES": {
        $ne: "$0.00"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                "PENALTIES": {
                  $eq: "$0.00"
                }
              },
              {
                "INTEREST": {
                  $ne: "$0.00"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "new-collection"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ags-q-M2PCY)